# AppComponent.html:7 ERROR TypeError: _co.getPosts is not a function at Object.eval [as handleEvent]

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to display results from API call using the button thought data.service.ts.Console shows this problem :

> AppComponent.html:7 ERROR TypeError: _co.getPosts is not a function at
>   Object.eval [as handleEvent]

Please help

App.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from './post';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'API';


}
```

App.component.html

```
    <div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <div>
    <button (click)="getPosts()"> Get Posts!</button>
  </div>

    <div>

    <input type='text'(keydown)="search($event)" placeholder='search posts...'>

    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <p><b>Title :</b> {{this.posts.title}}</p>
      <p><b>Body: </b>{{this.posts.body}}</p>
    </div>

    <div></div>
</div>



<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from './post';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  readonly ROOT_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

 posts: Observable<any[]>;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts() {
   this.posts = this.http.get<Post[]>(this.ROOT_URL + '/posts')
 }
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: your app component doesn't have `getPosts` method you should call `service.method`.inject data service and call the method like this https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getPosts() function is `undefined` because it is not defined in the `app.component.ts`. Instead it is just known in service which means you have to add it to `constructor` like this and then add method to app.component.ts

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
 getPosts() { 
   this.dataService.getPosts() 
}
```

But you don't return any value from the `DataService` so it will remain in the `Observable` known only in the `DataService`.

**If you want to display the result you need to return the value from `DataService`**

DataService.ts

```
getPosts() {
   return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.ROOT_URL + '/posts')
}
```

then you can save it to some variable in `app.component.ts`

```
getPosts() { 
  this.posts = this.dataService.getPosts() 
}
```

and update your html structure like this

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
  <p><b>Title :</b>{{post.title}}</p>
  <p><b>Body: </b>{{post.body}}</p>
</div>
```

By the way the `search($event)` is too calling some `undefined` function.

Comment: Is there any way I can return data? Previously, I didn't it without data. service and it displayed data with <button (click)="getPosts()"> Get Posts!</button>

Comment: @MarinaSinko The code with return of data is written under the bold sentence in my answer.